# How can set jinja variable in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

```
function show_modal(val1, val2){
    {% set msg1 = val1 %}
    {% set msg2 = val2 %}
    document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'
}
```

I have calling `show_modal()` function in some where in the template.

Needs each time assigning situational values to `msg1` and `msg2`

Not working. Each not working below:

```
function show_modal(){
    {% set msg1 = "Delete Column" %}
    {% set msg2 = "Are you sure you want to delete this column?" %}
    document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'
}
```

May I show different prompts with this part of code? (Which is invisible by default)

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
        <h1>{{ msg1 }}</h1>
        <p>{{ msg2 }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using external js file or the js code is within HTML file?

Comment: @itsmehemant7 Within template (HTML file).

Comment: After the page rendered, I can using `{% set msg1 = "Delete Column" %}` or `{% set count = namespace(value=0) %}` and so on...

Comment: In this case user click on Delete `button` and I need show him a warning prompt. This prompt have difference for each delete button. The page contains several Delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use pure js for this, try something like this:

```
function show_modal(){
   let msg1 = "Delete Column";
   let msg2 = "Are you sure you want to delete this column?";
   document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML=`
     <h1>${msg1}</h1>
     <p>${msg2}</p>`;
   document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'
 }

<div id="id01" class="modal">
</div>
```